# Is there a way that I can dynamically pass object names to a function (as arguments) and reference properties of that object using the argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the ID from imgs in my HTML, and pass those id's (which correspond to js objects that I've created) as arguments then access certain properties of those objects inside a function.

I've tried a variety of different methods to select the id of the child element, but I still get 'undefined' when I run the function because for some reason, passing the id as the argument doesn't allow me to access the keys of that object. I'm guessing that it's because the id is a string, and "string".key won't work. However, if that's the case, is there a way to dynamically get the object names and pass them as arguments? I'm still new, so if I'm not explaining myself well I apologize, hopefully, the code makes more sense.

```
let peas = {
    name : "peas",
    attack : 5,
    health : 100,
    counterAttack : 10,
    enemy : false
};
let broccoli = {
    name : "broccoli",
    attack : 5,
    health : 100,
    counterAttack : 10,
    enemy : false
};


 function battleFunction(player, computer) {
    //increments playerAttack
    newAttack += player.attack;
    player.health -= computer.counterAttack;

    //deducts attack from computer HP
    if (newAttack > player.attack) {
        computer.health -= newAttack;
        console.log(computer.health);
    } else {
        computer.health -= player.attack;
        console.log(computer.health);
    }

    if (computer.health <= 0) {
        defeatedEnemies++
    }
    if (defeatedEnemies >= 4) {
        alert("You won!");
        resetGame();
    }
};


$("#fightBtn").click( () => {
    battleFunction($("#playerDiv").children("img").attr("id"), $("#computerDiv").children("img").attr("id"));
});
```

I expect `$("#playerDiv").children("img").attr("id")` to return 'peas' and it does. Then, I expect player.attack in the function, to work like peas.attack.

If there's just a straight up a better way to do this, I am all ears.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can create a generic object called `mapNameToVar` that maps a string id to the corresponding variable, i.e, `let mapNameToVar = {"peas": peas, "broccoli": broccoli}`. Then you can do `battleFunction(mapNameToVar[$("#playerDiv").children("img").attr("id")], ...)`

Comment: Thanks for this comment! That might work, but after asking this question I actually realized that my real question was 'How do I convert a string to a variable name?' and that led me to the eval() method.

So, 

```battleFunction(eval($("#playerDiv").children("img").attr("id")), eval($("#computerDiv").children("img").attr("id")));```

Works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to this: *'How do I convert a string to a variable name?'*

First, you need a surrounding object. You can use the Window object, but it is not recommended. So, you can see here that I created a simple class that contains two properties that represent your objects "sullivan" is the player and "johnson" is the computer.

Since the Controller class wraps those variable names, then we can use the object created from the class, and use `[]` bracket notation to gain access to the properties like this:

`ctrl[player]`

Then if "player" points to the string "sullivan" we can gain access to sullivan's properties.

And you can see that internally to the class, we can access them using the `this` keyword:

`this[player]`

I've completed your example below. Let me know if you have questions:

```js
class Controller {

  constructor() {
    this.newAttack = 0;
    this.defeatedEnemies = 0;
    this.sullivan = {
      name: "Sullivan",
      attack: 4,
      health: 10
    };
    this.johnson = {
      name: "Johnson",
      counterAttack: 8,
      health: 10
    };
  }

  battleFunction(player, computer) {
    //increments playerAttack
    this.newAttack += this[player].attack;
    this[player].health -= this[computer].counterAttack;

    //deducts attack from computer HP
    if (this.newAttack > this[player].attack) {
      this[computer].health -= this.newAttack;
      console.log(this[computer].health);
    } else {
      this[computer].health -= this[player].attack;
      console.log(this[computer].health);
    }

    if (this[computer].health <= 0) {
      this.defeatedEnemies++
    }
    if (this.defeatedEnemies >= 4) {
      alert("You won!");
      //resetGame();
    }
  };

}
const ctrl = new Controller();
$("#fightBtn").click(() => {
  ctrl.battleFunction($("#playerDiv").children("img").attr("id"), $("#computerDiv").children("img").attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fightBtn">Fight!</button>

<div id="playerDiv"><img id="sullivan"></div>
<div id="computerDiv"><img id="johnson"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting and thank you for the detailed answer! I haven't messed around with constructors, classes, or the this/new keywords yet, so this is a bit above me, but I will dive into them.

One quick question, I need to have 5 potential player characters, so to create a new character in the example above I would just do:

this.bob = {
      name: "Bob",
      counterAttack: 8,
      health: 10
    };
And then if my user clicked the image with id "bobby" it still works, right? I imagne it will since nothing looks 'hard coded' within the battle function but just want to make sure.

Comment: `this.bob = { ... };` the element `id` would need to match the property name - so in this case that would be `bob` not `bobby`. For now, hard code it. But in the future come back and ask questions about how to structure things. you should get the help you need.